# Texturing along the edges of a rectangular box

Tags: 3d, glsl, webgl, texture-mapping

Starting from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52664748/4845566) I am trying to apply a texture with some transparent parts (png) just only to the edges of my rectangular prism.

[image]

My first try (left picture) is with a 4x4 texture using linear filtering. Here is the code:

```
// Normal direction branching
// M: coordinates, MN: normals of the model, sX,sY,sZ. size of the box
if( (abs(MN.x) > abs(MN.y)) && (abs(MN.x) > abs(MN.z)) ) {
  // X axis
  texCoords = M.yz / vec2(sY, sZ);
} else if( (abs(MN.z) > abs(MN.x)) && (abs(MN.z) > abs(MN.y)) ) {
  // Z axis
  texCoords = M.xy / vec2(sX, sY);
} else {
  // Y axis
  texCoords = M.xz / vec2(sX, sZ);
}
texCoords += vec2(0.5);
```

I am unhappy with that result because of the clearly visible artifact inside the sides of the box.
After that, I tried with a distance function and a 2x2 texture (center picture) but I am not able to parametrize the distance of the mapped texture from the edges of my box. This the code of my second attempt:

```
float squared(vec2 pos) {
  float at = (atan(pos.x, pos.y) + PI) / (2.0 * PI);
  float st = floor(at * 4.0 + 0.5) / 4.0;
  float dist = length(pos) * cos((at - st) * 2.0 * PI);
  return smoothstep(0.3, 1.0, dist);
}
// Here goes the same direction branching as above
texCoords *= squared(texCoords);
texCoords += vec2(0.5);
```

I am trying to achieve a result like in the picture on the right side, where my texture is applied all around the faces of my box, simulating a nice squared shading of the edges.

I am approaching distance functions right now, so I am unsure of what method shall be used here, and I am wonder if this would be the correct approach for what I am trying to do.

How can I map the texture coordinates around the faces of my boxes until a certain distance from the edges?

Comment: Is there some reason you not just putting precomputed texture coordinates in a buffer and passing them in an attribute like 99.9% of all apps? If you insist on doing it some non-standard way then it would make far more sense to pass extra per vertex data anyway so you can find the edges. [For example](http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/02/easy-wireframe-display-with-barycentric-coordinates/)

Comment: @gman: I have around 1k objects, I am trying to avoid to depend from a texture mapping tool, the same for vertex coloring. I am aware that a true edge recognition would be the perfect solution, but I can't effort a post-processing step. I will try to use extra vertex data ASAP.

Comment: I seem to vaguely remember that this sort of computation was nicely done in the geometry shader.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: could be, for some outline shaders, where you expand the geometry along the normals...

Comment: @gman: I forgot to mention the main reason, it is also because the texture coordinates may be used for the true texturing of the model.. so this will be a kind of overlapped shadowing.

Comment: You can have more than one set of texture coordinates

Comment: If you want to darken/lighten the edges you might want to employ shader-computed barycentric coordinates to compute true distances from the edges and then apply a mathematic darkening function instead of a texture. A good way to start is [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120527185124/http://cgg-journal.com/2008-2/06/index.html) (glsl code at the bottom). This way you have even more control and can easily draw antialiased thin edges and so on.

Comment: @Thomas: that's a great explanation of **Wireframe Drawing** but I need to map the coordinates just within a certain distance around my bounding box, not **all** edges. I will study it to see how I can change that code to my need.

Comment: @deblocker Well, for that box you show, the bounding box is the box itself and you state "but I am not able to parametrize the distance of the mapped texture from the edges of my box". That is exactly what is done in the link I posted. **Note that you have to draw your box as a quad mesh of course to avoid the diagonal to be shaded**.

Comment: @Thomas: yes, there is some useful math inside that great link, but I can't assume the geometry inside my bbox is only 12 triangles. Hope it is more clear now. I need to study it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has got one upvote, so I am posting here what I achieved.

This is my final result:

```
float borderSize = 0.5;
vec2 edgeDist;
float insideDist;
float outsideDist;
float dist;
if( (abs(MN.x) > abs(MN.y)) && (abs(MN.x) > abs(MN.z)) ) {
    // X major axis
    edgeDist = abs(M.zy) - 0.5 * vec2(sZ, sY);
} else if( (abs(MN.z) > abs(MN.x)) && (abs(MN.z) > abs(MN.y)) ) {
    // Z major axis
    edgeDist = abs(M.xy) - 0.5 * vec2(sX, sY);
} else {
    // Y major axis
    edgeDist = abs(M.zx) - 0.5 * vec2(sZ, sX);
}
insideDist = max(edgeDist.x, edgeDist.y);
outsideDist = max(insideDist, borderSize);
dist = (outsideDist - insideDist) / (2.0 * borderSize);
eCoords = vec2(smoothstep(0.1, 1.0, dist));
```

I still have to understand if it is possible to avoid the axis branching, but at least, I am happy with this result:

[image]

BTW:

the first example of this picture uses the 2x2 texture mentioned in my question, while the second example uses the same texture flipped vertically, and that *blueish* is the material color that pokes through the transparent part of the texture.